# Error pushing files to gitgub through gitHubDesktop

Tags: git, github

[image]

I am using Unity to playground with a trivia game I have just started and designing the loading page and added just one script. when I try to commit the files through gitHubDesktop it give me the error in the image uploaded. I'm not sure what to do because I cant commit my files let alone push them to github

Comment: You're not showing the entire error message.

Comment: They arent errors

Comment: They aren't of course, but who knows what's on bottom of the dialog box...

Comment: Please show us the entire error. Actually if possible don't post images of errors but rather include the full error message as text in your question. Also how is this related to Unity? And note that `unityscript` is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! when you open unity, it creates a file (UnityLockFile) I think this prevents commits and pushes (through github as far as I know)  A temporary fix for this, you either unselect the UnityLockFile on the list of updated flies to be commited or pushed, or you close (SAVE!!!) Unity entirely, then you can commit you files and push them.